# How to know when the user stop interacting with a SwiftUI Scrollview

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

I'm looking to know when a user stops touching the SwiftUI Scrollview but couldn't found a viable solution so far.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

The closest I've come to is observe the Runloop, but since I've several Scrollview displayed this does not seems suitable.

Comment: Wrap a `UIScrollView` instead.